# Optimal way to chain reverse foreign key lookups in Django

Tags: python, django

We have a DB model that looks something like this, where each arrow represents a many to one relationship in the direction of the arrow:

A --> B --> C --> D < -- E

For most models, we have a property called `D`. For `C`, that method returns `D`. For `B`, that method calls `C.D()` and so on. These we can use for FK lookup.

The problem arises for reverse lookups, since these chained properties are unavailable when generating SQL statements, meaning we would have to load the entire `QuerySet` into memory to filter on those properties. Ideally, we could do something like `A.objects.filter(D=someD)`.

What we instead do is lookup based on relations and chain a bunch of joins. The syntax is nice for one join, but it quickly becomes hard to maintain.

If we want to get all `A` objects related (indirectly) to `D`, we have to do`A.objects.filter(B__C__D=someD)`. Having to write code like this in multiple places is obviously not ideal.

We have looked into `F` annotations and a custom manager for each model without much luck.

TLDR: What's the optimal way to chain reverse lookups?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My first guess would be that when you have a lot of those kind of chain calls multiple levels deep maybe your data model doesn't represent the structure that you need very well. But since you didn't provide that it is only a guess. Codewise I would say you are already doing it the intended way,

Comment: If you want to improve filter performance, you can create a direct many2many relationship between A and D, update this list whenever a B-C or C-D relationship is added/changed/modified. I did this for a Student-Course-Batch-Branch relationship and was quite happy with the result